# android rhino not working on device, works on emulator

Tags: android, device, rhino

general question:

i have an app i'm developing that uses rhino to execute  java script code.

when i run it on my emulator it works well but when i install it on my device it crushes and gives a `Use *#9900# to take log` message.
 i am not sure what that error really means.

i have gone over the code and cleared all log and `system out` commands and added `debug=false` on the android manifest.

do i need to install on my device any other software,such as an interpreter so it could run java script?

Comment: Its a force close error, you see it on Samsung devices as they change the force close warning...post the full logcat of the error so we can see what the real problem might be

Comment: is it possible to see the log on the device?

Comment: hmmm if you write a logger that way but even if you do not write a custom logger it will still show all the js calls you just have to decipher what android OS calls them in the logcat